# How to use anti forgery token with ajax wcf service

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, antiforgerytoken

I have a ASP MVC website that is using wcf service via ajax in JSON encoding.
Is there any build in way to use anti forgery token with ajax <--> wcf service?

Here is how it's used in asp mvc apps.
http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/05/22/anti-forgery-request-recipes-for-asp-net-mvc-and-ajax.aspx

Comment: Please describe "anti forgery token". How is this different than a login session?

Comment: I assume he's referring to a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce).

Comment: If you dont know what is Anti forgery token than don even try to answer :). Generaly its way to prevent Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery
http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/05/22/anti-forgery-request-recipes-for-asp-net-mvc-and-ajax.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anti Forgery Token I'm sure your aware is available by default in the MVC framework , you are using Ajax to WCF  which really doesn't have anything to do with MVC except for concept your outlining.

You’re going done a long road to provide a security Ajax call via a MVC view to a WCF service.

First you'll need to use a Ajax Anti Forgery token implementation, please see below for links. You'll also need a database to manage your WCF tokens with an expiration date.

You'll need on load to dump out the WCF token and on every WCF request pass the token. the token will validated against the database. If the token has expired you'll need do another Ajax request with the AJAX Anti Forgery token to generate a new WCF token return the token and use this in your WCF Ajax request.

In conclusion you'll have two token one to validate your Ajax requests to your MVC controllers and the other for WCF requests.This approach will provide you with a secure request model to decrease the chance of a CSRF.

more about CSRF: http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-5.html

MVC Ajax anit Forgery token: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/

Hopefully this helps.